# How to merge multiple arrays in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'd like to read the content of multiple files, process their data individually (because of performance and hardware resources) and write my results into one 'big' netCDF4 file.

Right now I'm able to read the files, process their data, but I struggle with the resulting multiple arrays. I wasn't able to merge them correctly.

I've got a 3d array (time,long,lat) containing my calculated value for each day. What I like to do is to merge all the arrays I've got into one big array before I write it into my netCDF4 file. (all days in one array)

Here two example arrays:

- day1[19790101][-25][35]=95
- day2[19790102][-15][25]=93

My expected result is:

- allDays[19790101][-25][35]=95
- allDays[19790102][-15][25]=93

How can I achive that structure?

- When I use: `allDays=day1+day2` my data will be aggregated.
- When I use:

  ```
  allDays=[]
  allDays.append(day1)
  allDays.append(day2)
  ```

  my data will be surrounded by a new array.

FYI: I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and Python: 3.5 (Anaconda)

Comment: By arrays do you mean lists?

Comment: I work with numpy and print(type(day1))=<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
I'm new to python (coming from java)

Comment: I thought you could be talking about numpy arrays, just wasn't sure

Comment: Try `allDays.append(day1.tolist())`

Comment: @Reti43 no day2 won't have [19790101] but it could have the same lon & lat

Comment: both got the same shape: day1(1, 81, 141) ; day2(1, 81, 141)

Comment: no it is not valid, i wanted to show possible values within the examples to be more illustrative. I just tried that np.squeeze, but how will I achive a shape like this (n=number of all days) allDays.shape=(n,81,141)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106162/discussion-between-tharmar-and-reti43).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you do

```
allDays=[]
allDays.append(day1)
allDays.append(day2)
```

You are making a list of pointers to existing data, rather than repackaging the data. You could do:

```
allDays=[]
allDays.append(day1[:])
allDays.append(day2[:])
```

And now it will copy the data out of day1 and into the new allDays array. This will double your memory usage, so perhaps best to issue a `del day1` after each addition to allDays.

Having said all that, if you use Pandas (usually recommended for time series data) or Numpy, this whole thing would be a lot quicker and use a lot less memory. Numpy arrays cannot hold pointers like python lists can, so the copy there is implied. Hope that clears some things up for you :) I can also highly recommend [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AEJHKGk9ns) by Ned

Answer (score 14):

Now you can do something like this with python 3:

```py
tst1 = [1, 2, 3]
tst2 = [4, 5, 6]

ts3 = [*tst1, *tst2]
```

with results: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`

Answer (score 2):

Use `allDays = np.concatenate((day1, day2))`.

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with some random data.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> day1 = np.random.randint(255, size=(1, 81, 141))
```

Your  array has a dimension of size 1, so every time you want to access an element, you'll have to painstalkingly type `day1[0,x,y]`. You can remove that necessary dimension with [`np.squeeze()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html).

```
>>> day1[0,50,50]
36
>>> day1 = np.squeeze(day1)
>>> day1.shape
(81, 141)
>>> day1[50,50]
36
```

Now let's make some more of these.

```
>>> day2 = np.random.randint(255, size=day1.shape)
>>> day3 = np.random.randint(255, size=day1.shape)
```

You can put all of these in one big list and pass them to `np.array()` which will create an array of size `(N, 81, 141)`, where `N` is the number of days you have.

```
>>> allDays = np.array([day1, day2, day3])
>>> allDays.shape
(3, 81, 141)
```

All the data from `day1` are in index 0, from `day2` in index 1, etc.

```
>>> allDays[0,50,50]
36
```