# Merging of lists

Tags: python, list, data-structures

You have two lists say

```
ListA =['AB' , 'EF']
ListB = ['CD', 'GH']
```

Get a third list which will be like this

```
ListC =['AB', 'CD', 'EF', 'GH']
```

How to do it in Python?

Comment: The inputs in the lists can be any string what needs to be maintained is the sequence . Like list C will be basically  [index 0 of list A , index 0 of list B, index 1 of list A , index 1 of list B ....... so on]

Comment: Please provide the code that you have tried.

Comment: Potentially useful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35973828/56778. Also, you might want to add more detail to your question. Do you just want to concatenate two arrays? Do you want to remove duplicates? Do you want the resulting array to be sorted? You have to give us all the requirements, or we can't give you a decent answer.

Comment: Assuming that the elements present in the two lists are stings which cannot be sorted based on there inherent values but the resultant list should be in such a way created with sequence as mentioned above

Comment: The resultant list created will have elements in the form as [index 0 of list A , index 0 of list B, index 1 of list A , index 1 of list B ....... so on].....Hope I was able to provide the details with utmost clarity

Comment: Suggest adding the regular `python` tag for a wider audience, as this isn't Python 3 specific.

Comment: What you're asking for, then, isn't a "merge," but rather just a concatenation of the two lists.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to run a loop with 2 lists, you can always use zip()

```
ListA =['AB' , 'EF']
ListB = ['CD', 'GH']

ListC= []
for every in zip(ListA, ListB):
    ListC.extend(every)
```

Comment: This creates a list as [ ('AB', 'CD'), ('EF', 'GH')]

Comment: This is good one ...maybe it can be converted to a list with individual elems and not tuples in it.

Comment: It should create a list like ['AB', 'CD', 'EF', 'GH'] , but you must use extend()